Is there a way to make hot text (links) wrap (within the link when needed)?
I am implementing something like a breadcrumbs trail of hot (tap-able) text separated by separator characters and I want the whole thing to wrap as needed in the middle of the hot text if the need to wrap falls there. Because the crumbs are links, they have to be a collection of widgets, but displaying them in a Wrap object causes them to wrap on a per-widget basis and therefore never in the middle of the crumb links.

I tried to do this using Row, rows of Rows with the last one expanded, trying properties like softWrap on Text objects, "rich text," and more. I looked around for this use case, and posted to another forum. Seems like this should be possible in a mature app development framework.

I think RichText should be able to do this. How did you try this?

@Ivo Yes, I have tried RichText, but the widgets that make up the rich text collection will not individually wrap. The wrapping only takes place between the spanned widgets. Simple text will wrap, but if it's wrapped by a gesture object to make it interactive, the object as a whole won't wrap.

I can resort to breaking each word of each crumb into a separate widget, but it's very cumbersome doing that and one would think there is a better way to meet really a very basic UI need: A line of interactive texts that wrap where text would naturally wrap.

After a quick research, it turns out that TextSpan has a property that provides gesture recognizer in recognizer. This recognizer can be filled with many gesture recognizer such as TapGestureRecognizer that has similar ability with onTap in GestureDetector.
I provide example code of how this works:
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InlineLinkPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const InlineLinkPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Crumb separator.
    const TextSpan separator = TextSpan(text: ' | ');

    // Build crumb with [TextSpan] with the parameter [text] as [String].
    //
    // Usage Example:
    // ```
    // crumb('First Breadcrumb');
    // ```
    TextSpan crumb(String text) {
      // A function that triggered when the text is tapped.
      void handleTap() {
        // Write your logical [crumb] behavior when user tap the [crumb] here...
        print('Clicked: $text');
      }

      // Initialize [GestureRecognizer] for TextSpan. This is for detect tap
      // from user. 
      // 
      // In this case [recognizer] use [TapGestureRecognizer], The way it work 
      // is the same as [onTap] in [GestureDetector].
      // 
      // There's other option for [recognizer] like [LongPressGestureRecognizer()..onLongPress],
      // for detect long press on the widget.
      final recognizer = TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = handleTap;

      return TextSpan(
        text: text,
        recognizer: recognizer,
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Inline Link Page')),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),
              children: [
                crumb('This is first crumb'),
                separator,
                crumb('This is the second crumb'),
                separator,
                crumb('This is the third crumb'),
                separator,
                crumb('This is the fourth crumb'),
                separator,
                crumb('etc'),
                separator,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The Output


Possible issue
I don't see that TapGestureRecognizer has tapTargetSize to manage the tap area of the link, so the user needs to tap precisely inside TextSpan.
Recommendation
Adding line height to TextSpan will minimalize miss click case. Check this question for the insight.

Reference:

RichText
TextSpan
TapGestureRecognizer


Awesome! Looking forward to trying this shortly.

That did it. Thank you for your thoughtful answers. Will report this solution in a forum where responders thought it not possible.

You can use Text.rich() for inline widget/text case. With rich text we can use inline widget with text without any linebreak.
I provide simple code to show how Text.rich() works:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InlineLinkPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const InlineLinkPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Crumb separator.
    const TextSpan separator = TextSpan(text: ' | ');

    // Build crumb with [WidgetSpan] with the parameter [text] as [String].
    // 
    // Usage Example: 
    // ```
    // crumb('First Breadcrumb');
    // ```
    WidgetSpan crumb(String text) {
      return WidgetSpan(
        // This alignment handle vertical position of the [WidgedSpan]
        alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
        // [GestureDetector] can be changed to [TextButton], [ElevatedButton],
        // [OutlinedButton], or anything to handle the link.
        child: GestureDetector(
          // Handle your link function here
          onTap: () {
            // If the crumb clicked, the log will show
            // 'clicked: This is the .... crumb'.
            print('clicked: $text');
          },
          child: Text(text),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Inline Link Page')),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Text.rich(
            TextSpan(
              children: [
                crumb('This is the first crumb'),
                separator,
                crumb('This is the second crumb'),
                separator,
                crumb('This is the third crumb'),
                separator,
                crumb('This is the fourth crumb'),
                separator,
                crumb('etc'),
                separator,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The Output


For your information: you can use RichText too for this case.

If you try my demonstration code, if you click the text, it'll be show a log 'clicked: $crumbText'
Reference:

Text.rich official documentation
Richtext official documentation


I appreciate the effort very much. The issue is that those WidgetSpans will not wrap mid-widget, only between widgets. That's the issue at hand.

Oh i see what you mean, i think i misunderstood the question

Hello i just posted new answer, i guess it'll fulfill your needs. And i did on purpose make a new answer and let this answer there, in case someone needs this too. Thanks.
